# Can't pickle dataclass with lambda default

Tags: python, pickle, joblib, python-dataclasses

If I have a simple `dataclass` with a mutable default, as far as I know I need to use `default_factory`.

However, this makes the class unpickleable because of the lambda:

```
@dataclass
class ExperimentConfig:

    features: List[str] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: ["value1", "value2"])
```

So if we pickle it:

```
import cloudpickle
c = ExperimentConfig()
cloudpickle.dumps(c)
```

Pickling would return:

```
TypeError: can't pickle mappingproxy objects
```

That's due to the `mappingproxy` object visible in `c.__dataclass_fields__`:

```
{'features': 
    Field(name='features',
          type=typing.List[str],
          default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x7f6ca8434588>,
          default_factory=<function ExperimentConfig.<lambda> at 0x7f6c9951b268>,
          init=True,
          repr=True,
          hash=None,
          compare=True,
          metadata=mappingproxy({}),
          _field_type=_FIELD
         )
}
```

How do I make the class pickleable? I need to do so for sending it on a `Parallel` job with `joblib`.

Comment: It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle/issues/223) of cloudpickle.  The path of least resistance for you may be to use a regular class instead.  If you're not getting the primary benefit of dataclasses (simpler source code that's faster to write) then you may as well cut your losses.

Comment: "However, this makes the class unpickleable because of the lambda" Just don't use a `lambda` function???

Comment: [The lambda has nothing to do with this.](https://repl.it/repls/GrownPromotedGnudebugger)

Comment: @user2357112 Have things changed? That example seems to work for me now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Then don't do that!"

Comment: @Alec: Probably. The cloudpickle issue says it's fixed.